# Autocompletar com > após inserir sinal - no objeto

Tags: php, netbeans, autocompletar

Eu utilizava o NetBeans 8.0 e, codificando em PHP, após colocar a variável do objeto e o sinal de menos (-), automaticamente o editor incluia o sinal > para mim.

```
$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass- // neste momento, o editor completava o código, ficando da seguinte forma:

$myClass-> // e o editor exibia as opções de métodos e propriedades da classe
```

Depois que atualizei para a versão 8.2, este autocompletar parou de funcionar e não estou encontrando a opção nas configurações da ferramenta.

Alguém sabe onde eu consigo restaurar esta funcionalidade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o plugin [PHP Enhancements](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51791/php-enhancements/), que, entre outras pequenas melhorias, faz o trabalho perfeitamente.